# Rendering a single page application with data from the POST request to the server, in NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, serverside-javascript, viewrendering

I have a single page application which is pretty simple and basically starts out as a blank page. This app is designated to be a Facebook app - running in the Facebook Canvas.

Facebook loads my app by sending a POST request to my canvas URL, as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/).

I'd like to use the data from the POST request in my app, but I don't want to render it in the view itself, for example - 
`res.render('/index', postData)`

I want this data to be accessed directly by the JS running in my single page application. Is there a way to 'render' the data directly to the JS app ?

*Currently I'm using NodeJS/Express on the server side and my client side SPA is pure JS/Jquery/RequireJS. I'm not even using a view engine because my view is static and I'm good with a plain old static HTML file.*

Thanks !

Comment: Are you trying to do Ajax? Or, do you just want to use `JSON.stringify` to output the data as part of the page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _do Ajax_, but of course the whole idea is to avoid another call to the server. In this case, the data contains Facebook user data, which I'd like to use later on, e.g. when the user decides to post something from the app, but it's used by the JS and not displayed in the view.

Comment: How are you going to communicate the data to a fully static HTML page if you don't involve an Ajax request to the server?

Comment: The first request to the server already comes with all the data I need (in the POST body). Then I serve the SPA, but instead of rendering the view according to the request, I'd like to use that data directly in the JS I am also serving out, which is the code behind the app.

Comment: Are you just going to render it onto the page? You say that you want to use the data directly -- but I can't translate that to how you want to use the technology. You either need to render it onto the page as a block of JavaScript, or make an Ajax call. There really aren't many other options.

Comment: Render it onto the page as a block of JavaScript. What would be the best way of doing that ?

Comment: Thanks. So best practice is simply dumping a <script> tag in my view with var whatever={{JSON.stringify(mything)}} ?

Comment: It is "a practice." It sounds like it may be a good fit for your needs.

Comment: Guess it will have to do. I asked the question cause I figured there might be a more 'elegant' way to do it. Thanks for the help !